# Unit testing methods declared inside another method in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, reflection, sinon

i have a node module of the following format

```
'use strict’;

/// require dependencies here 

function outerFunc1(a, b, c) {

  function f1() {
    return f2()
  }

  function f2() {
    return 2
  }
  f1();
}
const choose = (type) => {
  let funcToCall
  switch (type) {
    case "func1":
      funcToCall = outerFunc1;
      break;
  }
  return funcToCall;
}

module.exports = (function () {
  return {
    choose
  };
})();
```

Can any one tell me how to unit test function f2 and f1 or in other words how can i invoke the same , is there any way to achieve the same like using reflection api or any other way using rewire or sinon ?

Comment: You probably need to refactor the code in your question.  `outerFunc2` does not exist.  `f1` and `f2` can never be called the way the code is written so it doesn't make much sense to try to test them.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors updated the code , can you please have a look once more ?

Comment: `f1` and `f2` are just *implementation details* of the function returned by `choose`.  It doesn't matter how the function is implemented, it just matters that it behaves as expected.  No code using this module will have any idea that `f1` and `f2` exist, they will just see the function returned by the `choose` export, so *just test that the function returned by `choose` behaves as expected*.  ([black box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing))

Answer (score 0):

All of the functionality of `f1` and `f2` can easily be stimulated indirectly from public API functions.  Therefore, there is no good reason to test them by themselves.  On the contrary, there are reasons agains testing them by themselves: Whenever the implementation of `outerFunc1` is changed, the chance that `f1` or `f2` are affected in a way that breaks the tests seems high.

Note, however, that I am not arguing generally against testing implementation details: You should definitely design your tests such that all potential bugs can be found - which means you should take implementation details into account.  Unit-testing is the right approach for this, because its purpose is exactly to test the smallest testable entities in the code using white-box knowledge.  For example, when you use branch coverage analysis to see whether you have missed some tests, you are making use of white-box knowledge about the code's control structure.

Some people argue you should not test implementation but behaviour only.  The reason is that otherwise the test suite can become fragile.  While it is certainly a valid goal to avoid that the test suite becomes unnecessarily fragile, it is nevertheless not the highest priority.  The highest priority is IMO that all the bugs in the production code can be found.  And that requires testing also the implementation details.

If some computation uses caching for faster re-producing already computed results, this would be an implementation detail from the user's perspective.  But, certainly, the caching algorithm can contain bugs, and thus the caching should be tested.  More generally, every subsystem (small or big) of an even bigger system can be seen as an implementation detail of the bigger system.  But that does not mean testing should only be done on the outermost system boundary.